# Downloading a file - how to?

Tags: android, download

My application is about a list with recycleview where you choose a file and you click on the download button , next it opens a webview which start the download of the file .

My app works fine for me but I've noticed that some users can't download those files and instead they open automatically with the default media player they have. Is there anyway when I can stop that ? please find bellow the webview class's code:

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new webviewclient());


    // ALLOW DOWNLOAD
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            final String filename= URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    // LOAD URL ( here where the download url start )
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }   
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}

public class webviewclient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        view.loadData("<html><head></head><body><center></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br><h1>OOPS! Error Occurred</br> </br>Error occuring due to internet connection Issue or server on maintanance.</br></br>Please check your internet connection and relaunch application.</br></br>Or</br></br> Try after sometime. </h1></body></html>", "text/html", null);
        webview_java.this.finish();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView client, String request) {
      client.loadUrl(request);
      return true;
    }

}
```

}

Manifest Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Comment: Why are you using a WebView to use the DownloadManager? You better do without.

Comment: @greenapps well to open the url ?

Comment: Which url? The download url? Not needed.

Comment: @greenapps yes the download url , can you give me the code plz ?

Comment: ????? You have the code already! Its in onDownloadStart().

Comment: @greenapps but it doesnt start until :     webView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: My god... You should not wait for onDownloadStart is called. Just take the code out and use that code instead of the webview. You should directly start the download manager.

Comment: @greenapps then what about the filename , how can I get it ?

Comment: You wanna download a file from an url. Is the file name contained in the url? You should tell us. You should tell what goes on.